# Is it possible to bind hiding/showing a UIAlertController in Mvvmcross?

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a command which interacts with an API. If the command doesn't return a desired result it sets a property of the ViewModel called Error.

I want to bind Error to a UIAlertController in my View and have it display when the error occurs.

Here's roughly what I have (although obviously the visibility converter isn't the way to go). I should add that I'm aware PresentViewController should be used to display the UIAlertController.

```
        UIAlertController myAlert = UIAlertController.Create ("", Error.Text, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        set.Bind(myAlert).For("Visibility").To((myViewModel vm) => vm.Error).WithConversion("Visibility");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Observer design pattern.
The way I prefer to achieve that is simple:

1. Create class which inherits from MvxMessage - let say ShowAlertDialogMessage with properties like title, content and so on.
2. Create abstract MessageObserver where TMessage : MvxMessage class, ex.:

   `public interface IMessageObserver
    {
        void Subscribe(IMvxMessenger messenger);
        void Unsubscribe();
   }`

   ```
   public abstract class MessageObserver<TMessage> : IMessageObserver where TMessage : MvxMessage
   { 
      public void Subscribe(IMvxMessenger messenger) {
          messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<TMessage>(OnMessageDelivered);
      }

      public abstract void OnMessageDelivered(TMessage message);
   }
   ```
3. Create MessageObserverController

`public class MessageObserverController {
    public void SubscribeObserver(IMessageObserver msgObserver) {
        msgObserver.Subscribe(messenger);
    }
    .. unsubscribe, dispose and so on goes here
}`

4. Implement ShowAlertDialogMessageObserver class (inherit from `MessageObserver<ShowAlertDialogMessage>()` which shows UIAlertViewController with data from ShowAlertDialogMessage (title, content and so on). Pass root UIViewController as constructor if needed (you will register MessageObservers in your viewcontrollers anyway - so that's not a problem).
5. Use `MessageObserverController` in your ViewControllers (preferably create base view controller to simplify things).

Voilà - you get reusable UI logic, which you can raise by publishing message in your PCL ViewModel (without creating any platform-specific coupling!).